# How to define a variable instead of table name in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
delete from Main.dbo.ACTIVITY;
insert into Main.dbo.ACTIVITY
select * from MainTemp.dbo.ACTIVITY;
```

and I want to execute that SQL for 10 tables after executing for `ACTIVITY`.

Is there any way to do that? Defining a variable or something?

I'm running the query in SQL Server Management Studio 10 (= SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use dynamic SQL

```
declare @tablename sysname = N'ACTIVITY';
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'delete from Main.dbo.' + quotename(@tablename);
exec sp_executesql @sql;
set @sql = N'insert into Main.dbo.' + quotename(@tablename);
exec sp_executesql @sql;
set @sql = N'select * from Main.dbo.' + quotename(@tablename);
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

It is **very** important to use the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) when handling dynamic SQL because of the SQL injection risk. Dynamic SQL has pros and cons, for an in dept discussion see [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

### Use [SQLCMD execution mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx)

SSMS and SQLCMD have capabilities to use client side variable substitution:

```
:setvar tablename Main.dbo.ACTIVITY
delete from $(tablename);
insert into $(tablename);
select * from $(tablename);
```

Where SQLCMD mode variables shine is when used in batches because the variables can be passed in via the [-v argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). For example:

```
c:\>for /f %i in (tablenames.txt) do sqlcmd -S <servername> -E -d <dbname> -v tablename=%i -Q "truncate table $(tablename)"
```

Note that in SSMS the SQLCMD execution mode must be enabled explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Write dynamic query in that case. The below example may give you some idea

e.g.

```
Declare @tableNames table(Id int identity,TableNames Varchar(10))
Insert Into @tableNames Values('Table1'),('Table2'),('Table3'),('Table4')

Declare @query AS Varchar(max)
Declare @tblNames AS Varchar(max)
Declare @count AS int
Declare @i AS int = 1

Select @count = Count(*) from @tableNames

While(@i <=@count)

Begin
    Select @tblNames = TableNames from @tableNames Where Id = @i
    Set  @query = 'delete from ' + @tblNames 
    Set @query +=  '; insert into ' +  @tblNames
    Set @query +=  '; select * from ' +  @tblNames

    print @query --exec  @query 

    Set @i += 1
End
```