# Variable has unexpected NULL value in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have searched high and low, without finding an answer. So I hope that you guys n girls can help me on my way:

I cant figure out why @old_comment is NULL when I use it in "SET @new_comment...", but it returns a fine value when I use it in the outputparameter "SET @commentOldOUT..."

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NY_KOMMENTAR]
    @tabel NVARCHAR(100),
    @id INT,
    @comment NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @commentOldOUT NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @user NVARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @new_id VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @new_comment NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @old_comment NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @old_comm NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @old NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @q2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @new_id = (SELECT CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(100)));
    SET @user = (SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN());
    SET @date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()));
    SET @old = 'SELECT comment FROM '+ @tabel +' WHERE id = ' + @ny_id;

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @old, 
        @params = N'@old_comm NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', 
        @old_com =  @old_comm OUTPUT;

    SET @old_comment = (SELECT @old_comm);

    SET @commentOldOUT = @old_comment;                          

    SET @new_comment = COALESCE(@old_comment + CHAR(13),'') + '[' + @user + ' ' + @date + '] ' + @comment;

    SET @q2 = N'UPDATE ' + @tabel + ' SET comment = ''' + @new_comment + ''' WHERE id = ' + @ny_id;
    EXEC (@q2);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I tried your query but for me it works fine! Have you tried to "debug" your query? You can see the value of every variable when in debug. (The green arrow in SQL Server 2008)

Comment: When I debug it, the @old_comment is not assigned by `    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @old, 
        @params = N'@old_comm NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', 
        @old_comm =  @old_comm OUTPUT;

    SET @old_comment = (SELECT @old_comm);`

Comment: Thank you for hinting me the debugging, I'm not used to work with SQL Server and SSMS, I may say that I unfortunately is more of an Oracle guy...

Comment: Well Oracle is good too. I learned Oracle in school but I switched to SQL Server because of my job. Now, I only do SQL Server. I'm glad I helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you didn't pass a value explicitly for the `@comment` parameter? If so, the problem would be here:

`SET @new_comment = COALESCE(@old_comment + CHAR(13),'') + '[' + @user + ' ' + @date + '] ' + @comment;`

The parameter `@comment` has a default value of `NULL` and concatenating anything with `NULL` results in `NULL`. That would explain why `@old_comment`, `@user` and `@date` all have values, but when it put it all together then `@new_comment` is `NULL`. This would be a better default value:

`@comment NVARCHAR(1000) = '',`

And your code as written is a bit messy, I assume that `@old_comment` and `@commentOldOUT` are only for debugging purposes? I don't see why you don't use `@old_comm` directly.

Finally, if you're working with dynamic SQL then I strongly recommend adding [a debugging parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739306/setting-variables-in-sql-functions-probs/10739598#10739598) to print out your SQL strings easily. It's a very useful troubleshooting tool, especially if you don't have SSMS available.

Comment: The `@comment` parameter was carried through correctly, but the dynamic SELECT-statement didn't return anything.

Comment: @ClausHjortBube Can you clarify your question? You asked why a variable is `NULL` but now you're saying that the `SELECT` doesn't return anything. What precisely is the problem you have? And I see that you have a variable in your `SELECT` for the table name; you can't use variables directly in place of object names so the `SELECT` shouldn't work at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374782/how-to-define-a-variable-instead-of-table-name-in-sql

Comment: I can now see that I didn't know to ask the right question... I couldn't understand why @old_comment didn't got set. I have played with so many versions of this SP that I lost track. My last problem is now solved thanks to your guiding about the table-variable! I have updated my _answer_ with the working stored procedure. Not sure if it is the right thing to do, perhaps there are other less gifted, like me, that can benefit from it...

Answer (score 0):

Well I can now see that I did several things wrong, below is the new, and now working, stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NY_KOMMENTAR]
    @tabel NVARCHAR(100),
    @id INT,
    @comment NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
IF @comment IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @user NVARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE @SQLSelect nvarchar(500);
        DECLARE @ParmSelect nvarchar(500);
        DECLARE @old_comment NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @old_commentOUT NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @new_comment NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @SQLUpdate nvarchar(500);
        DECLARE @ParmUpdate nvarchar(500);

        SET @user = (SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN());
        SET @date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()));
        SET @SQLSelect = N'SELECT @old_commentOUT = kommentar FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tabel) + ' WHERE id = @id';
        SET @ParmSelect = N'@id INT, @old_commentOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';

        EXEC sp_executesql 
            @SQLSelect,
            @ParmSelect,
            @id = @id,
            @old_commentOUT = @old_comment OUTPUT;

        SET @old_comment = (SELECT @old_comment);
        SET @new_comment = COALESCE(@old_comment + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),'') + '[' + @user + ' ' + @date + '] ' + @comment;

        SET @SQLUpdate = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tabel) + ' SET kommentar = @new_comment WHERE id = @id';
        SET @ParmUpdate = N'@id INT, @new_comment NVARCHAR(MAX)';
        EXEC sp_executesql 
            @SQLUpdate, 
            @ParmUpdate,
            @id = @id,
            @new_comment = @new_comment;
    END
```

For example I weren't using parameterbinding correct, after that I tried to bind tabelnames as a parameter...