# Using Table Name as a parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I use the table name as a parameter in a stored procedure?

I am doing it like this but I'm getting an error

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TablesReporting_GetTableData]
    @tableName as VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @tablename
END
```

Error:

> Must declare the table variable "@tableName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
SET @cmd = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in that format.  You need to embed the variable into dynamic SQL and execute it.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(100), @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @TABLENAME = 'myTable'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLENAME
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TablesReporting_GetTableData]

    @tableName AS VARCHAR(100)= NULL -- NULL default value
AS
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max)= 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tablename

-- Validate the @tablename parameter.
IF @tablename IS NULL
BEGIN
   PRINT 'ERROR: You must specify the table name.'
   RETURN
END

exec sp_executesql @query

RETURN
GO
```

Here, i have just created and executed dynamic query.

To achieve in other manner using SqlCMD mode you can take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374782/how-to-define-a-variable-instead-of-table-name-in-sql).